# How to escape from loop Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I need to write a conventer (Celsius to Kelvin,Kelvin to Celsius...). User write: a - degrees(for example 0), b - for example: Kelvin, c - for example: Celsius.

Exercise:
Input Format
There are a few input lines.
Each line consist of three words.
First word indicates starting temperature.
Second word indicates starting scale.
Third word indicates target scale.

Constraints
Possible scales are: {"Kelvin", "Celsius", "Fahrenheit"}. Temperatures are up to 1000 degrees. Whenever initial temperature is below Absolute zero output "NO".
Number in the output should maintain precision up to second decimal place.

Output Format
For each input line one number that is the calculated temperature (with precision of two decimal places) or word "NO".

This is for hackerank

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users...", line 4, in <module>
    a, b, c = input().split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
```

Code:

```
while True:
    a, b, c = input().split()
    if int(a) < 0:
        print('NO')
    else:
```

Leave the loop when user stop writing.

Comment: while True:
    a, b, c = input().split()
    if int(a) < 0:
        print('NO')
    else:

Comment: You need to specify the meaning of "when user stops writing" in programmatic terms.  Then test for that condition.  Since you haven't told us what it means, we can't "correct" your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Our immediate need is that you fully describe your problem in the posting; not in a comment, not under an answer, not using an off-site link with no explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a guess at one possible solution:

```
a, b, c = input().split()
```

This code requires exactly three non-blank fields in the line.  You could test for that;

```
user_stuff = input().split()
if len(user_stuff) != 3:
    break
a, b, c = user_stuff
```

---

Your link implies that you're reading from a file piped to `stdin`, rather than from live user input.  In that case, you have to treat `sys.stdin` as a file:

```
from sys import stdin

for line in stdin:
    a, b, c = line.split()
    ...
```

Comment: It works but [link](https://imgur.com/a/kfPjJ9Z) I have the same problem, when i tried to do it with ''try/except''